# RadioButtonList Grouping In Labels

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I need your help with this one, I don't know if it is possible.

Imagine a RadioButtonList populated from a Database using a databind from vb codebehind looking like this;

```
[1]  - Apple      -    Fruit  
[2]  - Banana      -   Fruit  
[3]  - Beetroot    -   Vegetable 
[4]  - Orange      -   Fruit   
[5]  - Strawberry  -   Fruit  
[6]  - Carrot      -   Vegetable  
[7]  - Potato      -   Vegetable
```

Now I want to make it look like this;

```
- [Fruit]
     - Apple
     - Banana
     - Orange
     - Strawberry
- [Vegetable]
     - Beetroot
     - Carrot
     - Potato
```

I think I am able to group the radio button somehow or change the label. I also thought about using a tree node which I have not used before.

Comment: what type of project are you using?  MVC?  WebForms?

Comment: you should use treeview in asp.net webform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK you can not use attributes on radio buttons or list box items. The attribute is added to the parent only. You can achieve this by rewriting the DOM I have seen on another forum, requires a lot of the work I just will create 2 radio buttons to get me going. Its funny because if I was using PHP I could call a radio button list or select list and populate whatever attribute I wanted. Well Done Microsoft for removing this common use function! Just like the onkeyup events and ondblclick are only available client side.

Answer (score 2):

if use webform read this article:
https://weblogs.asp.net/alaaalnajjar/group-options-in-dropdownlist

if your ptoject is mvc you must use selected list:

```
   public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public static List<Car> GetCars()
    {
        return new List<Car>{
            new Car{Id=1, Name="Volvo", Category="Swedish Cars"},
            new Car{Id=2, Name="Mercedes-Benz", Category="German Cars"},
            new Car{Id=3, Name="Saab", Category="Swedish Cars"},
            new Car{Id=4, Name="Audi", Category="German Cars"},
            new Car{Id=5, Name="Audi", Category="German Cars"},

        };
    }
}


public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.CarsList = GetCarsSelectList();
        return View();
    }

    private SelectList GetCarsSelectList()
    {
        return new SelectList(Car.GetCars(), "Id", "Name","Category",1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, I am using vb code but I can convert to vb no problem, I will give it a go and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I cant seem to get your code working correctly, you are on the correct path to what I want. I just tried create a listbox binding from the database then on the databind was trying to add attribute of optgroup which only adds to the header of the select box instead of the option value. The same problem occurs if you wanted the 3rd row coloured in a dropdownlist, it would colour the whole thing.